# How to change global variable inside function

Tags: python-3.x, function, scope, global-variables

I have simplified my problem, using the code below to demonstrate my issue.

```
apples = 0
bananas = 0
euro = 10
dollar = 5


def buy(fruit, money):
    fruit += 1
    money -= 1


buy(apples, euro)
print(apples)
print(euro)

buy(bananas, dollar)
print(bananas)
print(dollar)
```

I want my function to change the variables so that the output of my code above returns:
1,
9,
1,
4,
but instead it outputs:
0,
10,
0,
5,

I can't use 'global apples' or 'global fruit' as I want to be able to buy more than one kind of fruit.
I also can't use 'return apples' as I want to change two different variables inside my function.

How can I code it so that the variables change after put them through my function?

Comment: put the prining in the buy function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change and return two variables in a function. You can modify your function as below.

```
apples = 0
bananas = 0
euro = 10
dollar = 5

def buy(fruit, money):
    fruit += 1
    money -= 1
    return fruit, money

apples, euro = buy(apples, euro)
```

Function will return two values fruit and money. Their values will be assigned to the global variables after return.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't know that you can return two items from one function.

Answer (score 0):

Since `int` is not a mutable type, you cannot modify the global variable as you would like. A possible option is to use dictionaries to store your global data and pass the name of the fruit and the money to your function:

```
def buy(fruit, money):
    fruits[fruit] += 1
    monies[money] -= 1


fruits = {
    "apples": 0,
    "bananas": 0
}

monies = {
    "euro": 10,
    "dollar": 5
}

buy("apples", "euro")
print(fruits["apples"])
print(monies["euro"])

buy("bananas", "dollar")
print(fruits["bananas"])
print(monies["dollar"])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I knew it worked with lists but not with dictionaries.

Comment: @YXWEB No problem. Lists, dictionaries and sets are mutable so they will be able to do what you are attempting to.